# Simple gantt-like timeline chart tool?

Tags: linux, open-source, project-management, data-visualization, planning

I'd like to plan a travel itinerary in a Gantt-chart-like fashion. This is what I'd like:

- Zoom in down to resolution of less than an hour, zoom out to resolution of months
- Ability to set "task" start/end time manually, or through GUI
- Works and saves file offline (but a JavaScript/HTML solution that I can run locally is OK)
- Hopefully can indicate "dependencies" on the timeline with arrows
- Free/Open Source for Linux

So far, I have looked at these applications:

- **GanttProject** - cannot zoom in at resolution of hours, events cannot be set in terms of hours 
   [image: GanttProject.png]
- **ProjectLibre** - Can zoom in to hours, task/events start/end can be set in terms of hours - but it adds constraints automatically, and you cannot set an end of the event beyond the declared end of work day - unless you do something with custom calendars which I really don't understand 
   [image: ProjectLibre.png]
- **planner** - can zoom into hours, but cannot set task start and end in hours 
   [image: planner.png]

ProjectLibre might in principle be suitable - but I find this setting up of custom calendars and work day constraints extremely difficult, just to be able to write in "task" that represents a flight landing (say) Saturday afternoon.

Is there anything simpler I could use for something like this - a Gantt chart like a visualization of a travel plan/itinerary?

---

EDIT: Also related: [jquery - javascript gantt charts -charting data by day/hour/minutes - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270678/javascript-gantt-charts-charting-data-by-day-hour-minutes) (however, not very easy to use); also [SIMILE Widgets | Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/), but you have to write code manually, and there seems to be no zoom

Comment: For Mac OS X and iOS, there is [OmniPlan](https://www.omnigroup.com/omniplan/) by the OmniGroup.

Comment: I always liked TaskJuggler and this page seems to indicate that you can bring the task resolution down to 5 minutes(!)  http://www.taskjuggler.org/tj3/manual/timingresolution.html

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a native gantt or even a dedicated planning tool, but definitely zooming: [iMapping](http://www.imapping.info)

- Zoom in down, zoom out √

  - You can nest Objects as deep as you want and zoom very deeply by factor more than 10000
- Ability to set "task" start/end time manually,

  - there are no form fields or such, but
- ... or through GUI (√)

  - You can make objects (boxes) any size/width/length and write in them whatever you want
- Works and saves file offline √
- can indicate "dependencies" on the timeline with arrows √
- Free/Open Source for Linux (√)

  - Free for up to 300 items / map. Possibly, you can even get the full version free for linux.

Disclaimer: The iMapping Tool is developed by me.

Comment: Please disclose that this is your tool.

Answer (score 1):

All your requirements are met by [RationalPlan Single](http://www.rationalplan.com/single-project-management-software.php) which is free for Linux:

- versus GanttProject: You can zoom in up to minutes
- versus ProjectLibre: It does not set constraints on tasks if you link them but if you drag them to a certain date or change the start date a constraint will be added to stay at that date... it is all about [project management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management). If you do not like the Standard predefined 8 hours per day calendar you can use the 24 hours one or even declare your own working calendar which is really easy to be done.
- versus Planner: You can set a custom date format to enter even hours

Note: I am one of the developers of this product.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and I just found that Notion.so has a "Timeline view", similar to a Gantt view:

[image]